# In OPL is there a way to maximize one parameter and minimize another?

Tags: cplex

I want to run a problem to maximize NPV and minimize a certain cost at the same time. Is it possible to run a maximization and minimization problem at the same time?

Is there a way out in OPL?

Answer (score 2):

You could use staticLex as in

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.mod

And then use minus:

```
maximize staticLex(npv,-cost)
```

Which will maximize npv and then minimize cost.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex said, the 'lexical' multi-objective approach is great. However, you can achieve more flexibility and understanding if you think a bit more about what is going on. A simplistic approach to doing something similar from scratch would be to solve for the first objective ignoring the second so that you know the best possible value of e.g. NPV. Then change your objective function to minimise the cost instead of maximising NPV, and add a constraint that fixes the NPV to be within e.g. 0.1% (or 1% or 2%) of the maximum possible value that you found in the first solve, and solve the new problem. This approach lets you explore the trade-offs between the two objectives - maybe there are big savings in the cost if you can accept a small drop-off in the NPV.

The 'out of the box' built-in multi-objective stuff is much easier and almost certainly more efficient than doing it yourself - just wanted to share some of the ideas behind that black-box magic. It's good to know a bit of how you can make things work for you.